# Are invalid left side assignments a compilation error or evaluation error in compiling

Tags: compilation

I am writing a compiler

Using JavaScript as an example,

If I wrote the following

```
function foo (){return “bar”} 
foo() = 1;
```

I would get a vm error.

Obviously foo returns a string, which cannot be assigned too, and predictably returns an error.

But is this a parse error? Or is it an evaluation error.

Where is the error trapping handled?

Should this be capture during the ast construction or at run time?

Is this language specific? What is the genera practice regarding tbis

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing in perl. i

```
$ perl -c
sub foo () {return 'bar'}
my $bar = \&foo;
$bar->() = 'test';

- syntax OK
```

versus executing it

```
 $ perl
sub foo () {return 'bar'}
my $bar = \&foo;
$bar->() = 'test';
Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call of &main::foo at - line 3.
```

so it appears, yes, this is a run time error. meaning  dont worry about it when constructing your parse tree!

this may not be the case in C, but in interpreted lanaguages, it appears at least that if its syntactically correct, and not egregiously incorrect, this compiles.